# Related posts: Get records by tags from different tables

Tags: php, mysql, schema

I'm working on a news site. Like every news site there will be news, columns, videos and photo galleries. I'm planning to keep these different types of records in different tables but relate them with tags. Here is a simple schema:

Tables: News, Videos, Galleries, Columns, Tags, Post_to_tags

Post_to_tags:
- tagid
- postid
- posttype [news,video,gallery,column]

Now what I need to do is get related records for a post in a single query. It's easy to join one table and get related posts but when it comes to different tables... Any idea?

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail? It's not clear what you're asking for.

Comment: Could you explain what do you want to select exactly?

Comment: I need to get every related record from different tables. As I said it's easy to join one table, but I have to join different tables depending on posttype.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to do it in two queries, as doing it in one query will be quite ugly, and may not buy you much in terms of speed.

So you would use the tags to get all the postids that relate, then just do a join to get the articles and associated records that relate to the postids.

```
select n.*, g.*, v.* FROM News n 
   INNER JOIN Galleries g ON(g.postid=n.postid) 
   INNER JOIN Videos v ON(v.postid=n.postid) 
   WHERE n.postid IN(
     (SELECT p.postid FROM Post_to_tags p WHERE ...)
   )
```

This should be a starting point, but I see your problem, as you have posttype.

Why not ignore posttype for this query and just use the same postid, for the story, so they have a way to be searched easily.

Answer (score 0):

If your query is getting the same number of fields with the same datatypes, you can use a UNION.

```
SELECT fielda, fieldb FROM news n 
  JOIN post_to_tags p ON (n.post_id=p.post_id) 
  where p.tag_id='x' and p.post_type='news'
UNION
SELECT fielda, fieldb FROM videos v 
  JOIN post_to_tags p ON (v.post_id=p.post_id) 
  where p.tag_id='x' and p.post_type='videos'
```

But if this is the case, you may want to reconsider your schema.  Something like:

- Post table with fields common to all
  post types, and a flag field for post
  type
- Details_X tables with fields specific
  to type X posts

will allow a single query:

```
SELECT fielda, fieldb FROM posts p 
  JOIN post_to_tags pt ON (p.post_id=pt.post_id) 
  where pt.tag_id='x';
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion about table schema. I'm thinking that too. I'm also thinking to store post_link and post_title in the post_to_tags table. So I won't need to use join. But every way has it's own problems. Performance will be very important. So I'm looking for "cheapest" solution.